# Azure DNS record pointing to Azure CDN is not propagating to external DNS servers

Tags: azure-cdn, azure-dns

I have a website hosted in Azure using the Azure CDN.  The DNS entry for the root domain (`ohsopleasant.com`) is configured to point to the Azure Resource for the CDN.

[image]

When I do a DNS lookup directly against the Azure DNS servers, the DNS record resolves correctly to the same IP as the CDN endpoint (`ohsopleasant.azureedge.net`):

```
> nslookup ohsopleasant.azureedge.net
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    sni1gl.wpc.mucdn.net
Addresses:  2606:2800:11f:1cb7:261b:1f9c:2074:3c
          152.195.19.97
Aliases:  ohsopleasant.azureedge.net
          ohsopleasant.ec.azureedge.net
          scdn13725.wpc.bc6ef.mucdn.net
```

```
> nslookup ohsopleasant.com ns1-09.azure-dns.com
Name:    ohsopleasant.com
Address:  152.195.19.97
```

But if I do a DNS lookup against my ISP's DNS server (comcast), or against Google's DNS servers (`8.8.8.8`), it returns a completely different IP address:

```
> nslookup ohsopleasant.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ohsopleasant.com
Address:  34.98.99.30

> nslookup ohsopleasant.com 8.8.8.8
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ohsopleasant.com
Address:  34.98.99.30
```

**I can't figure out why the Azure DNS records aren't propagating to the rest of the Internet or why they're pointing at a GoDaddy "parked DNS" website.  Any ideas what's configured incorrectly?**

Answer (score 0):

The issue, it turns out, is that the App Service Domain record that I created in order to register the domain via Azure was inadvertently deleted.  This resulted in the authoritative DNS for the domain falling back to GoDaddy, the service Azure uses for domain registration.  Since the Azure DNS servers are no longer the authoritative DNS for this domain, their entries are not being propagated to other servers.

Unfortunately, after contacting Azure Support, it seems that there's no way to restore the App Service Domain if it's been more that 30 days since it's been deleted, so I'm out of luck on this one and have effectively lost the domain.